# Can I use Google Apps Script with Google Voice to create interactive menus or other Voice XML like services?

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried searching Google's forums, but couldn't find anything remotely similar. Does Google Apps Script allow this type of interactivity with Google Voice? Where can I find some sample source code?